# Need help in increasing the quality of images in flash/as3 with a restriction of 45 kbs total swf size

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a "Flash banner ads" project and i want some help on it. The guideline is to restrict the total size of the swf to 45 kbs.

I am using TweenNano from greesock so my animations are not that much heavier.

But there are lots of images in the fla. Still i have managed to do the animations and included the images and the file size is within 45 kbs range.

My problem is that the quality of the images is not good. **Is there any way we can improve the image quality by as3 or is there any other technique i should use ??** If u want more details i can provide them.... or suggest some image compression technique without reducing the quality...

Thanks

Comment: At An Event Apart, they mentioned a technique that has recently been discovered, which is to make your JPGs twice the size, at zero quality, then scale them down. They look the same or better, but are smaller.

Comment: That's an interesting technique! A few things I do include: recreating any simple cartoony graphics as vectors in Flash; replacing transparent pngs with jpgs and cutting the shapes out in Flash; making smooth backgrounds by blurring low-res images; grouping images into sprite sheets. Any space savings can be used to improve the compression on vital images.

Comment: if "quality of the images" is because of pixelation of some kind, you could add a blur filter to reduce the apparent pixelation - it can improve image quality in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is limiting the SWF's size to 45kb, you don't have much options to increase image quality. First, you may make some vector graphics instead of raster and display that. And second, you can load the images from elsewhere via `URLLoader` class, for this, make sure to add security context for non-local images, and make sure your ad displayer won't frown upon this.

Answer (score 0):

Alright here's what i did with the final project. (And let me mention you that i was able to decrease the file size upto 40kbs)

- I had a total of 11 images (each with 300dpi resolution) and i have to make a flash banner ad within 45kbs of file size.
- First thing first... i used TweenNano by GreenSock for the animations
- kept the resolution of the images to 300 and decrease their size (height/width) according to my needs in Photoshop and then used "Save for web"
- I used png-8 format and in some cases png-24
- Import the images to flash and go to properties of the images -> use png (loss-less) compression (Now u may think it will increase the file size... but that was fine because i wanted to maintain some quality too)
- I have converted all text to vectors
- Used movieclips
- In the publish settings too U can compress the swf file.
- There is a check box saying "Include xmp metadata" -> i unchecked it and it also helped me to save some kbs

That was it... if in case this information might help someone.. they can use it. :)